# Do the eigenvalues and the roots of characteristic function coincide for the matrices with entries in a P.I.D?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I encounter with a problem like this: Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain, A be an upper triangular matrix in $R^{n\times n}$, then the set of eigenvalues of A is same as the set of diagonal entries of of A.

I think it suffices to show the eigenvalues of A, defined by $Au=\lambda u$, coincide with the zeros of the characteristic function of the matrix(defined by $det(\lambda I-A)$). But I don't know how to use the condition that $R$ is P.I.D.

Plus, I am not sure if the statement

$(\lambda I-A)X=0$ has nontrivial solutions iff $det(\lambda I-A)=0$

will fail for $R$.

Could anybody show me how to deal with such a problem about the matrices on P.I.D? Thank you!

Comment: You don't need anything about PIDs here ("princip*al*", by the way). It suffices that $R$ is an integral domain. Then, $R$ embeds into the quotient field $F$ of $R$, and $\lambda I-A$ has a nontrivial kernel in $R^n$ if and only if $\lambda I-A$ has a nontrivial kernel in $F^n$ (because you can multiply through any vector in $F^n$ with the common denominator of its entries).